# Возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Пишу простой калькулятор:

```
const operators = {
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
};

function calculator(string) {
  const arr = string.split(' ');
  const a = Number(arr.shift())
  const b = Number(arr.pop())
  
  arr.forEach((token) => {
    if (token in operators) {
      return operators[token](a, b);
    }
  });
};

console.log(calculator('3 + 4'))
```

Пытаюсь осуществить операцию с помощью объекта который по оператору возвращает результат.
В консоле выводиться undefined. Насколько я пока понял проблема в том, что я вызываю функцию((a, b) => a - b) в forEach.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать такой подход?

Comment: В функции calculator нет ни одного return, вот она и возвращает по умолчанию ничего, то есть undefined

Comment: Замените forEach на обычный цикл for, например

Comment: Спасибо! это же так очевидно))

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculator(string) {
  const operators = {
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b,
      };
  const arr = string.split(' ');
  const a = Number(arr.shift())
  const b = Number(arr.pop())
  
  arr.forEach((token) => {
    if (token in operators) {
      result = operators[token](a, b);
    }
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(calculator('3 + 4'))
```

вернет 7